# I faced a problem when I used .env file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, mongodb-atlas

In my node.js project, I want to use environment variables for saving MongoDB's user name and password. When I directly use username and password then it is working completely. But when I used template string and `process.env.varName` then I got `bad auth: Authentication failed` error message.

```
ok: 0,<br/>
code: 8000,<br/>
codeName: 'AtlasError',<br/>
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0)<br/>
{}
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: please share your code for mongodb connection